# I can't figure out how to send a single data from my Arduino to a single column on the excel?

Tags: excel, arduino, arduino-uno, data-stream

I'm sending a data from my Arduino color sensor to excel using data streamer but whenever I see my data all three numbers(the red, blue and green values) appear on the same column. How can I make them appear on separate column? Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, I just add

```
Serial.print(",");
```

before every

```
Serial.print(color);
```